# Wordpress the_category(); only works with message-posts not with project posts, how do I specify project categories?

Tags: posts, categories

The title, the permalinks & even the field of ACF do work smoothly. But the code is not reactive to project categories, when I echo wp_list_categories(); it shows the list of message posts only. How do I specify that it should echo project categories instead?
Current code:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'project', 'posts_per_page' => 10);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

echo '<ul>';
echo '<li>';the_title(); echo '</li>';
echo '<li>';wp_list_categories(); echo '</li>';
echo '<li>';the_category(); echo '</li>';
echo '<li>';the_field(Prijs); echo '</li>';
echo '</ul>';

endwhile;
```

Comment: Are you registered any taxonomy for "project" post type?

Comment: Nope, I just realized projects is a custom post type from Divi. I'm gonna look into taxonomy now!

Comment: hopefully get_the_term_list will help you. See the codex for more details https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_category` and `wp_list_categories` are for the `category` taxonomy term. What most people call a category is most likely a taxonomy. Category is just a default taxonomy for the `post` post type.

You need to use the general taxonomy functions such as [the_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_terms/) and  [get_the_term_list](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/).

```
echo '<li>'; echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'project_category'); echo '</li>';
```

You will need to change `project_category` to whatever custom taxonomy name you have used.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex, it worked! Just pasting your code did the trick.